# Passing Spring Security auth.getName() to frontend

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I have application with Spring Security, I want to pass logged user name to my html view.
What is best practice to do this operation?
Now i have rest controller method, and I access to logged user name through ajax request, but I think this is not the best practice:

```
    @GetMapping(value = "/user/getSecuredUserName")
    public String getSecuredUserName(){
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    return auth.getName();
}
```

Do You have any advice how to pass logged username to frontend with more elegant way?

Comment: It depends on what you're using for frontend, is it a SPA, embedded jsp/thymeleaf? Either way, in your controller you can use the `Authentication` object as a parameter of the method, something like this: `public String getSecuredUsername(Authentication auth)`.

Comment: Now in fronted i have pure html, so I should change it to jsp and pass parameter through something like this: model.addAttribute("name", SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName()); ?

Comment: If you're using JSP you can just use the security tag libs, what's described here would do https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-taglibs#authentication

Comment: I think it is ok as you wrote or Marcos. 
The following is a little off topic, but might interest you also. I would change the path to comply with some REST stands. "getSecuredUserName" sounds like a verb, while the verb should be expressed by used HTTP method "GET". What do you think about "/user/myName"